# Assigning card values

Tags: python, playing-cards

Is there a better way to do this?

This function takes, as an argument, a natural number, n, which is between 1 and 52 inclusive and returns a list containing the point value associated with that number as an integer. The aces are the numbers 1,14,27,40 in the respective suits and they worth either 1 or 11 points. The regular cards with the numbers 2-10,15-23,28-36,41-49 in their respective suits are worth their face values. The face cards
are represented by the numbers 11-13,24-26,37-39,50-52 in their respective suits and they are each worth 10 points.

```
def getPoints(n):
    #the ace values
    if n == 1 or n == 14 or n == 27 or n == 40:
        return [1,11]
    #the regular card values
    if 2<=n<=10:
        return [n]
    if n == 15 or n == 28 or n == 41:
        return [2]
    if n == 16 or n == 29 or n == 42:
        return [3]
    if n == 17 or n == 30 or n == 43:
        return [4]
    if n == 18 or n == 31 or n == 44:
        return [5]
    if n == 19 or n == 32 or n == 45:
        return [6]
    if n == 20 or n == 33 or n == 46:
        return [7]
    if n == 21 or n == 34 or n == 47:
        return [8]
    if n == 22 or n == 35 or n == 48:
        return [9]
    if n == 23 or n == 36 or n == 49:
        return [10]
    if 11<=n<=13 or 24<=n<=26 or 37<=n<=39 or 50<=n<=52:
        return [10]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with variable-assignment.

Comment: Instead of a linear list of numbers, why not use strings: `"5spades"` or `"5S"`? Or even better, tuples: `(5, "S")`?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: If you have chains of `if` statements there is almost always a better way. (Not always, but *almost* always)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of making a function that maps a number from 1 to 52 you can reduce your domain to 1 to 13, and use modulo 13 to every number. That will reduce 75% of your conditions. It is done with a bit of modulo math.
Then this function becomes quite short:

```
def getPoints(n):
    n = (n-1) % 13 + 1
    #the ace values
    if n == 1:
        return [1,11]
    #the regular card values
    if 2<=n<=10:
        return [n]
    if 11<=n<=13:
        return [10]
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can improve easily is replacing `n == 15 or n == 28 or n == 41:` with `n in [15, 28, 41]`

Other thing you can try is to use a loop like:

```
for i in xrange(9):
    if n in [15 + i, 28 + i, 41 + i]:
       return [2 + i]
```